# angular custom filter only return results where boolean === true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am using a custom filter within an `ng-repeat` list in Angular 1.

The filter is successfully filtering search results, however it is not working as I need it to.

Currently, resulted are filtered based on whether the filter cat is present.
E.g 'cleaning' or 'DIY' or 'marketing'

However, the filter is *not* checking to see if the boolean is `true` or `false`.

So results where 'cleaning : false' are included in the same ng-repeat as where 'cleaning : true'

I only want to return the results if the filter object (e.g cleaning) evaluates to `true`.

I don't have much experience writing my own filters so any input or push in the right direction would be **really** appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here is the option select drop down:

```
<select class="sortBy" ng-model="selectedCat" ng-value="x.filter" ng-options="x.cat for x in taskCategories">
</select>
```

Here is the array which the filter is checking against, each object in the array has a title to display in a drop down select option, and the filter I want it to run:

```
$scope.taskCategories = [{
      'cat': 'All',
      'filter': ''
    }, {
      'cat': 'Cleaning',
      'filter': 'cleaning: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Moving & Delivery',
      'filter': 'moving: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'DIY',
      'filter': 'DIY: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Marketing & Design',
      'filter': 'marketing: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Digital & IT',
      'filter': 'onlineIT: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Events & Photography',
      'filter': 'photoEvents: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Business & Admin',
      'filter': 'office: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Fun & Quirky',
      'filter': 'funQuirky: true'
    }, {
      'cat': 'Misc & Other ',
      'filter': 'misc: true'
    }];
```

**Here is the custom filter:**

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
return function(items, search) {
  if (!search) {
    return items;
  }
  return items.filter(function(element) {

    //attempt 1      
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(function(x) {
      return x === search.substring(0, search.indexOf(':'));
    });
    //attempt 2 
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(function(x) {
      return x === search.substring(0, 2);
    });
    //attempt 3 
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(function(x) {
      return x === search;
    });
    //attempt 4
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(element).find(function(x) {
      if(x === true) {
      return x === search.substring(0);
      }
    }); 

  });
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be making the filter be 2 different properties?

so have it like `{
      'cat': 'Moving & Delivery',
      'filter': {'moving', true}
    }`

Now inside your filters.
check against each part to decide whether it should be added.
so one check if its the same bool by using filter[1] and one check if the item has property of filter[0].